# Find a class-path in Dymola

Tags: module, block, modelica, dymola

Does anybody know how can I find the path of a class in Dymola? E.g. the ones shown in the picture below.

[image: Unknown Class 1]

[image: Unknown Class 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top one is a `MixingBox` from `Modelica Buildings Library`. The bottom one also looks like a component from the said library.

Comment: I couldnt find the bottom one . do u know its exact name?

Answer (score 2):

When you double-click any component the information should be shown in the parameter dialog as marked red below.

[image: Properties of inertia1 in Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller]

You can see this dialog after double-clicking the `inertia1` in the example `Modelica.Blocks.Examples.PID_Controller` as marked red below.

Additionally you could take a look a the Modelica code directly...